# how to add a class at first position using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have an element with more than 5 classes. I just need to replace the class in first position without affecting the rest of them ..

I don't want to replace all classes (I have tried with .attr('class','class1 class2 class3 class4 class5') , .prop , .switchclass etc)..

Comment: Why does it matter where in the list of class-names this new close is inserted?

Comment: I'm using jquery validation engine and select2.js.. validation engine works only if the class in first position

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use jQuery for that: just address DOM Element and its `className` attribute directly. For example (assuming `$el` is a jQuery object wrapped aroung the element you want to change):

```
$el[0].className = $el[0].className.replace(/^\S+/, replacementClass);
```

This replaces the first class of `$el` with `replacementClass` string.

Alternatively, you can use `attr` to do essentially the same:

```
$el.attr('class', function(_, cls) {
  return cls.replace(/^\S+/, replacementClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggleClass()` to add/remove a class or `removeClass()` to remove class and then use `addClass()` to add the new class.

Example:
DOM:

```
<div class="a b c d"></div>
```

JS:

```
var ele = $("div.a");
ele.removeClass("a").addClass("e");
// OR
ele.toggleClass("a").addClass("e");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this:

```
<p class='classA classB classC'></p>
```

jQuery:

```
var classes = $('p').attr("class").split(" ");
var newClass = 'myClassEdited';
var classes[0] = newClass;
$('p').attr('class', classes.join(" "));
```

Edited DOM:

```
<p class='myClassEdited classB classC'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a class in first position look at **raina77ow answer and other answers**. but the **last class is more power than first class**.

for example

```
class1 class2 class3 class4 class5

class5 {
   color:red
}

class1{
   color:green

}
```

so color red will apply for all the text class1 is not useful it is dummy

Answer (score 0):

One further approach:

```js
// elem: DOM Node, on which the class-name will be toggled,
// toggleClass: String, the class-name to toggle.
function prependClassToggle(elem, toggleClass) {
  // if the element currently had the passed-in class-name
  if (elem.classList.contains(toggleClass)) {
    // we remove it, using the classList API's remove() method:
    elem.classList.remove(toggleClass);
  } else {
    // otherwise we concatenate the passed-in class-name with the
    // string returned by the className property (and a space):
    elem.className = toggleClass + ' ' + elem.className;
  }
}

// document.querySelector() returns only the first element matching the selector, or null,
document.querySelector('button')
  // assigning event-handling behaviour for that <button>:
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
  // calling the function, passing in the <button>'s nextElementSibling,
  // and the string of the classname to add:
  prependClassToggle(this.nextElementSibling, 'classA');
});
```

```css
div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle 'classA'</button>
<div class="classB classC classD classE classF"></div>
```

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className).
- [`Node.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling).

Answer (score 0):

> Its very Simple thing. Only use
>
> **element.addClass('YourClass');**
>
> for removing Any Class
>
> **element.removeClass('YourClass');**